# Write a function that takes in a list of letters and returns the highest scoring word that can be made with the letters

Tags: python, list

The function bestWord(Rack) takes an input Rack (which is a list of letters) and returns a list with two elements: the highest possible scoring word from that Rack followed by its score. If there are ties, they can be broken arbitrarily. Another list called scrabbleScore is provided so you know the value of each letter, as well as Dictionary which consists of the words that can be created with the letters.

```
scrabbleScores = [ ["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1], 
         ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8], 
         ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1], ["p", 3], 
         ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], ["u", 1], ["v", 4], 
         ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10] ]

Dictionary = ["a", "am", "at", "apple", "bat", "bar", "babble", "can",
          "foo", "spam", "spammy", "zzyzva"]
```

Example:

```
>>> bestWord(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"]) 
>>> ['spam', 8]
```

I can only use expressions made up of list comprehensions(map, filter, etc.) and have to keep scrabbleScores as a list and not a dictionary. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me this or help me understand map and filter better.

Comment: This question has been asked before, and the reasons for those silly restrictions was never explained. The restrictions are also vague. Please clarify both points. And have you looked up `map` and `filter` in the Python documentation or on a search engine?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).